# Ajax request not posting ID to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have wrote an AJAX post request to my deletewidget controller,  it is posting the request token fine, however it does not seem to pass the widgetID to the controller.  I have stepped through the javascript code and it assigns the ID to the variable widgetID fine, and have also put a breakpoint in my controller but it says null.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#columns').on('click', '.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash', function (event) {
        var panel = this;
        //get id here

        //toggle the modal
        $('#deleteWidgetModal').modal('show');
        var widgetID = $(this).closest('.panel.panel-default').attr('data-widgetid');

        document.getElementById('delete-widget').onclick = function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();

            //anti forgery token
            //get the form
            var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
            //from the form get the antiforgerytoken
            var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

            var URL = '/Dashboard/DeleteWidgetConfirmed';

            //we make an ajax call to the controller on click
            //because the controller has a AntiForgeryToken attribute
            //we need to get the token from the form and pass it with the ajax call.
            $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                data: {
                    __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                    id: widgetID   
                },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(result){
                    var parentElement = $(panel).closest(".col-md-4.column");
                    var targetElement = $(panel).closest(".panel.panel-default");
                    targetElement.remove();

                    //parentElement.addClass("expand-panel");
                    checkEmptyPanelContainers();
                    $('#deleteWidgetModal').modal('hide');
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("An error has occurred please contact admin");
                }
            })
        }
        return false;
    })
});
```

and here is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteWidgetConfirmed(int? id)
    {
        if(id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        WidgetModel widgetModel = db.widgets.Find(id);
        db.widgets.Remove(widgetModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Comment: Check 'widgetID' scope. you declare and access in separate methods.

Comment: So should I get the widgetID when the second button is clicked?

Comment: I think now  it undefined right ?

Comment: Are you sure that the value of ID is assigned to widgetID?

Comment: I hovered over it and it had a value

Comment: You can try by changing ".attr('data-widgetid')" to ".getAttribute('data-widgetid')".

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be executing the ajax code twice, I moved my return false up one level and it solved the problem